# How can i convert dropbox log timestamp?

Tags: android, logging, frameworks, timestamp, dropbox

I am debugging a android framework.
I pull out dropbox logs from device and it's created in /data/system/dropbox.
Log file name is printed like this format.

event_data@1362451303699

1362451303699 is timestamp and i want to change it like 05/03/2013 16:00 for legibility.

How can i convert this timestamp?
Is there any code needs to be changed?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use: `Date date = new Date(timestamp);`

Edit full code:

```
String wantedDate = "";
String log = "event_data@1362451303699";
int index = log.indexOf("@");
if(index != -1) {
  index = index + 1; // skip @ symbol
  if(index < log.length()) { // avoid out of bounds
    String logtime = log.substring(+1);
    try {
      long timestamp = Long.parseLong(logtime);
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
      Date date = new Date(timestamp);
      wantedDate = df.format(date);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // not a number 
    }
  }
}
if( ! "".equals(wantedDate) ) {
       // everything OK
} else {
       // error cannot retrieve date!
}
```

Related doc:

- indexOf : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29
- SimpleDateFormat : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Do you know a specific directory where exist source code file? I couldn't find a file because there are too many files in android folder.

Comment: File what generating dropbox log files. i just can pull out a dropbox log.

Comment: According to that http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/dropbox-not-installed-but-there-is-log-activity-in-data-system-dropbox url it seems that `/data/system/dropbox` is a system folder

Answer (score 0):

you can use a SimepleDateFormat to parse it. For example:

```
long ts = 1362451303699;
Date date = new Date(ts);    
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

With the `SimpleDateFormat` you can bring your Date in a more readable format.

Answer (score 0):

It is a UNIX epoch timestamp, all you need to do is to convert the `String` representation of the number to `long`, then you can use it to create a `Date` object, which you can format with `DateFormat`. Something like this:

```
// Get this from the log
String timestamp = "1362451303699";
long epoch = Long.parseLong(timestamp);
Date date = new Date(epoch);

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
String formattedDate = format.format(date);
```